# JQuery custom alert box dosnt run automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jquery alert library named [Apprise2](https://github.com/ThrivingKings/Apprise-v2/blob/master/apprise-v2.js), it works fine when im using it for alerts in my form validation function. all i want is to show alert on page load, i call it at the end of the page, but it dont work, this is what i use at the end of page :

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['lasterror'] == '1') {?>
    <script>
        Apprise('error-occured');
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

when im using "alert" instead of "apprise" it works and shows the alert, i linked to the library bellow and i hope you can help me with this problem. thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: no :) php side is correct

Comment: Nothing on the JavaScript side either?

Comment: have you included the necessary scripts (jQuery and apprise-v2) **before**?

Comment: yes i included jquery and apprise-v2, and it works when i call it from my form validation script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this in `doc ready` handler:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['lasterror'] == '1') {?>
    <script>
       $(function(){
          Apprise('error-occured');
       });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Point 2: this might be the issue:

You are testing a string which might be a number here:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['lasterror'] == '1') {?>
//-----------------------------------^-------here
```

Comment: @user2932025 you are checking for a string which might be a number, have you seen this point2

Comment: thanks so much, worked fine :) and thanks again for the second point you mentioned :)